# Is it possible to limit the number of items in an array without using slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return only 4 items. But, because I am filtering by date I am showing events equal to or greater than today's date. Slice wont work for me.

For example, when I use slice it works properly and only shows 4 items (i am assuming). But those items dates already past so nothing shows because of the conditional.

Can I limit the `.map()` to show only 4 items without `.slice(0, 4)`?

Example code:

```
{data.adv_events.data.slice(0, 4).map((event, i) => (
  <div className="event col-12" key={i}>
    {event.start_date.unix >= today &&
    <div className="row event-item">
      <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
        <div className="event-date mb-3">
          <p className="month"><Moment format="MMM">{event.start_date.unformatted}</Moment></p>
          <p className="date"><Moment format="DD">{event.start_date.unformatted}</Moment></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-9 event-title">
          <span className="time">{event.start_date.time} - {event.end_date.time}</span>
          <a href={`${event.cost_registration_link.uri}`} target="_blank">
            <p className="bold mb-0">{he.decode(`${event.title}`)}</p>
          </a>
          {event.schools.map((school, i) => (
            <span key={i}>{school.name}</span>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
    }
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: If the problem is that the sliced array probably won't have the kinds of items you want, could you do the `slice` *after* the `map`, so that you're slicing down known-good items? Possibly you want a `filter` in there (to limit the array to elements matching some predicate function) instead of a `slice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use filter ahead of time in order to only keep rows you care about. And then you can slice like you had before.

```
{data.adv_events.data.filter(event=>event.start_date.unix>=today).slice(0, 4).map((event, i) => (
  <div className="event col-12" key={i}>
    <div className="row event-item">
      <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
        <div className="event-date mb-3">
          <p className="month"><Moment format="MMM">{event.start_date.unformatted}</Moment></p>
          <p className="date"><Moment format="DD">{event.start_date.unformatted}</Moment></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-9 event-title">
          <span className="time">{event.start_date.time} - {event.end_date.time}</span>
          <a href={`${event.cost_registration_link.uri}`} target="_blank">
            <p className="bold mb-0">{he.decode(`${event.title}`)}</p>
          </a>
          {event.schools.map((school, i) => (
            <span key={i}>{school.name}</span>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) inside `map()`

Change from this

```
{data.adv_events.data.slice(0, 4).map((event, i) => (
  ...
))}
```

to

```
{data.adv_events.data.map((event, i) => (i < 4 &&
  ...
))}
```

---

Update: If there are additional conditions, refer to [the above post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61033990/11872246) use filter instead would be fine.

Comment: This is fine for an alternative to slice but the events will still be hidden because they are past